# ROW_NUMBER vs IDENTITY and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any difference (in terms of result set, performance or semantic meaning) between using ROW_NUMBER and using IDENTITY with an ORDER BY statement in MS SQL Server?  For instance, given a table with a column "FirstName" is there any difference between

```
SELECT FirstName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName) AS Position
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM MyTable
```

and

```
SELECT FirstName, IDENTITY(BIGINT) AS Position
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY FirstName
```

Comment: Take a look at the execution plans of both options. That would give you a pretty good indicator for performance. I doubt there will be much difference.

Comment: @scsimon not 100% sure about that

Comment: @scsimon the second query has an order by so the output will be the same. And by definition a table has no order.

Comment: Ah missed the OrderBy thanks @SeanLange

Comment: `IDENTITY()` only works when also using `SELECT ... INTO`, so if you wanted to do a simple `SELECT` (to see what you are inserting before you do) - it would throw an error.

Comment: I've looked into execution plan and they are the same. I did some testings with 1.6 million records, but couldn't found any replicable result about speed difference between them. They were alike, although ROW_NUMBER version ran 40% slower on the first try. So I can't conclude much from this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semantic meaning is different.  The first example creates an integer column with a sequential value.

The second example, using `identity()` creates an *identity* column.  That means that subsequent inserts will increment.

For instance, run this code:

```
select 'a' as x, identity(int, 1, 1) as id
into #t;

insert into #t(x) values('b');

select *
from #t;
```

As for processing, the two should be essentially the same in your case, because the `firstname` needs to be sorted.  If the rows were wider, I wouldn't be surprised if the `row_number()` version edged out the other in performance.  With `row_number()` only one column is sorted and then mapped back to the original data.  With `identity()` the entire row needs to be sorted.  This difference in performance is just informed speculation.